# ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe in JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm trying to figure out how I can pass a stream of data within `ContentProvider.openFile`.  The data to be sent is created in JNI.  I tried `createPipe` with a transfer thread but I had a ton of trouble with broken pipes.  So I thought I might just pass the 'write' pipe to JNI and write the data directly to it.

Java:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor[] pipe = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
boolean result = ImageProcessor.getThumb(fd/*source fd*/, pipe[1].getFd()); //JNI call (formerly returned a byte[])
return pipe[0];
```

C:

```
unsigned char* jpeg = NULL;
unsigned long jpegSize = 0;

getThumbnail(env, &jpeg, &jpegSize, rawProcessor); // Populates jpeg thumb, works when converted to byte[] in second segment
FILE* out = fdopen(dest, "wb");
int written = fwrite(jpeg, 1, jpegSize, out);
return TRUE;
```

When I convert to byte[] everything works fine, just not within a `ContentProvider` obviously:

```
jbyteArray thumb = env->NewByteArray(jpegSize);
env->SetByteArrayRegion(thumb, 0, jpegSize, (jbyte *) jpeg);
free(jpeg);
return thumb;
```

When I debug it gets to `fwrite` then the stack trace just seems to disappear.  Never hits `return TRUE` or `return pipe[0]`, but also doesn't crash or throw.  Very strange...

Has anyone done something similar?  Is it sufficient to simply write binary to the "write" pipe?  Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong here?  Thanks.

### Update (after discussion with @pskink)

I tried implementing the `PipeDataWriter`.  I used [FileProvider.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/87cfef9/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/content/FileProvider.java) as an example.

```
@Override
public void writeDataToPipe(@NonNull ParcelFileDescriptor output, @NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mimeType, @Nullable Bundle opts, @Nullable byte[] args)
{
    try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(output.getFileDescriptor()))
    {
        fout.write(args, 0, args.length);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed transferring", e);
    }
}
```

---

```
byte[] rawData = ImageUtil.getRawThumb(fd.getParcelFileDescriptor().getFd());
return openPipeHelper(Uri.parse("invalid"), "image/jpg", null, rawData, this);
```

However, I'm getting the same errors I got when I used the transfer thread above:

> java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
>   at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:498)
>   at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
>   at
>   com.anthonymandra.content.MetaProvider.writeDataToPipe(MetaProvider.java:273)

and

> java.io.IOException: write failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
>   at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:498)
>   at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
>   at
>   com.anthonymandra.content.MetaProvider.writeDataToPipe(MetaProvider.java:273)

When I stepped through to make sure the data was fine for the images I found that everything loaded fine.  It looks to me like this is actually a thread safety issue.

Comment: you mean [this](http://pastebin.com/Z41vickG)?

Comment: Ok, so a transfer thread is still needed.  That makes some sense.  I was doubtful of the "magic memory backing" assumption I was making.  That also probably means I'll run into the same broken pipe issue, but I'll give it a shot real fast.

Comment: see `ContentProvider#openPipeHelper` then

Comment: I did glance at that initially, before I had any idea what a pipe was, but wrote it off with the `URI` and hence supported mimeType requirement.  I should have looked again once I was learning the ropes here.  Thanks.  I'll update when I hammer out the transfer to see if it behaves any better than a simple `ByteArrayInputStream` -> `ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseOutputStream(pipe[1])`.  That threw endless broken pipe errors, using TranferThread from https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ContentProvider/Pipe/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/cp/pipe/PipeProvider.java

Comment: i did not try to "marry" `openPipeHelper` with jni but i am 99.99% sure you could just call `ImageProcessor.getThumb(fd/*source fd*/, pipe[1].getFd());` inside `PipeDataWriter#writeDataToPipe` method

Comment: Initially I thought it wouldn't work since my source wasn't a `Uri`, but I guess you could use the `opts` to insert the source as a `Parcelable` in the end.

Comment: you can pass *anything* in the `args` (the last but one param of `openPipeHelper`)

Comment: Haha <facepalm>

Comment: I updated the question with my results.  Looks like it's actually a thread safety issue and I was chasing a red herring.

Comment: hmm, i cannot understand yours `writeDataToPipe` method, i actually meant something like [this](http://pastebin.com/cmBbUuKJ)

Comment: Originally the native output was a byte[].  I thought the issue was in the large transfer thread so I tried moving the pipe write to native which is the original question.  When you pointed me to the PipeDataWriter and I saw the Google example I decided to try the byte[] again which was easier to debug.

Comment: so does it work now? btw you dont need extra `FILE*` layer: `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_org_pskink_poly_MyContentProvider_nativePipeWriter (JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jint fd) {
    const char* str = ">>> it works too :-) <<<";
    write(fd, str, strlen(str));
}`

Comment: gallery adapter calls `openInputStream`.  That in turn calls `openFile`.  A native call (`byte[] rawData = ImageUtil.getRawThumb`) extracts a byte[] jpg thumb from the image sent by the gallery.  That byte[] is written in full to the write side of the pipe (`writeDataToPipe`).  The read side is sent back, which `ContentResolver` turns into the requested `InputStream`

Comment: i mean if you tried the code i sent in my [prev comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954047/parcelfiledescriptor-createpipe-in-jni#comment73011091_42954047)

Comment: I tried something very similar. I believe it works. I discovered one issue, which was that I wasn't closing the PFD in a finally. The pipe errors aren't fatal, but the StrictMode was killing the app for that. I was then able to clearly see that every image is being loaded twice: 4 images; 4 `openInputStream`; 8 `openFile` (2 each).  I think this is leading to the pipe errors. I can't quite explain why, especially since I temporarily synchronized openFile to try to minimize threading conflicts. I'll have to keep hacking at this but I think I'm on the right track now.

Comment: I figured it all out and put it in an answer.  In the end your suggestion to use the `PipeDataWriter` was right, there were just a bunch of other issues.  If you want to post an answer I'll accept that and leave my answer as supplemental data.

Answer (score 0):

There were actually a bunch of things going wrong that all rolled up into a confusing mess:

1. I wasn't closing the `ParcelFileDescriptor` in a finally.
2. I use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for an image cache and it uses two fetchers when you load a `Uri`, meaning `openFile` was being [called twice per file](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1811#issuecomment-288574768).
3. (2) caused endless broken pipe errors.
4. `StrictMode` was killing the app because of (1) and I missed it in the flurry of errors from (3).

Comment: great, but actually when using `PipeDataWriter` you dont have to close `ParcelFileDescriptor` since the "writing end" is closed [here](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/ContentProvider.java#1676) and "reading end" is being closed [here](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.java#862) (when closing the `InputStream` created by a `ContentResolver#openInputStream()` method)

Comment: There was actually another pfd involved.  The thumb data (which is piped) is an extraction from a raw image which is acquired through the awful SAF as a PFD.  That needed to be closed properly in case of error (bad pipe) which caused `StrictMode` to kill the app (and get lost in a flurry of error messages).